# Draw an arrow to the edge of a node in a tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, tikz-arrows, tikz-node, tikz-path

I have written this latex document:

```
\documentclass[dvipsnames,aspectratio=169,10pt,fleqn]{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}

\usefonttheme{serif}
\usecolortheme[named=Mahogany]{structure}


\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,mindmap,trees,backgrounds}
\tikzstyle{every picture}+=[remember picture]
\tikzstyle{na} = [baseline=-.5ex]
\tikzset{
    invisible/.style={opacity=0,text opacity=0},
    visible on/.style={alt=#1{}{invisible}},
    alt/.code args={<#1>#2#3}{%
      \alt<#1>{\pgfkeysalso{#2}}{\pgfkeysalso{#3}}
    },
}

\tikzset{
  background fill/.style={fill=#1},
  background fill/.default={white},
  fill on/.style={alt=#1{}{background fill}},
}

\tikzset{
  background draw/.style={draw=#1},
  background draw/.default={white},
  draw on/.style={alt=#1{}{background draw}},
}

\tikzset{
  background filldraw/.style 2 args={draw=#1, fill=#2},
  background filldraw/.default={white}{white},
  filldraw on/.style={alt=#1{}{background filldraw}},
}

\tikzset{
  background shade/.style={#1},
  background shade/.default={top color=white, bottom color=white},
  shade on/.style={alt=#1{}{background shade}},
}

\tikzset{
  background shadedraw/.style 2 args={draw=#1, #2},
  background shadedraw/.default={white}{top color=white, bottom color=white},
  shadedraw on/.style={alt=#1{}{background shadedraw}},
}



\newcommand{\tikzmark}[1]{\tikz[remember picture] \node[coordinate] (#1) {#1};}

\setbeamerfont{caption}{size=\tiny}
\setlength\abovecaptionskip{0pt}
\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]

\usetikzlibrary{positioning, shapes.arrows,shadows.blur}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,backgrounds}



\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Example}

    \begin{columns}
    \begin{column}{.5\textwidth}

    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[]
                \node [inner sep=0pt,above right]
                {\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{test.png}};

                \path (1.3,0.7) coordinate (Nodefig);
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \end{column}


    \begin{column}{.5\textwidth}

     \tikz[baseline]{ \node[align=center] (n1) {Test};}

    \end{column}
    \end{columns}




 \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
         \draw<1-> [thin, red,opacity=.3, fill=red,fill opacity=0.2](Nodefig) ellipse (2cm and 1.5cm);

         \path[->,line width=0.8pt,color=BrickRed]<1-> (n1) edge [out=-180, in=0] (Nodefig);
 \end{tikzpicture}

\end{frame}



\end{document}
```

and this is the result:

[image]

However, I would like that the arrow stops right on the edge of the red ellipse. I have looked to different post but still I am not able to get what I want. The problem here, I suppose, is that I work within the tikzpicture and command like above, west or east seem not working.

Could someone give me glue?
Thanks

Comment: Your MWE doesn't reproduce showed result. So I wonder,, what is in your Image `test.png`. Image of `\LaTeX` command?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of manually drawing an ellipse, you can use the `ellipse` node shape. This way the arrow will automatically stop at the edge of the node:

```
\documentclass[dvipsnames,aspectratio=169,10pt,fleqn]{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}

\usefonttheme{serif}
\usecolortheme[named=Mahogany]{structure}


\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,mindmap,trees,backgrounds}
\tikzset{every picture/.append style={remember picture}}
\tikzset{na/.style={baseline=-.5ex}}
\tikzset{
    invisible/.style={opacity=0,text opacity=0},
    visible on/.style={alt=#1{}{invisible}},
    alt/.code args={<#1>#2#3}{%
      \alt<#1>{\pgfkeysalso{#2}}{\pgfkeysalso{#3}}
    },
}

\tikzset{
  background fill/.style={fill=#1},
  background fill/.default={white},
  fill on/.style={alt=#1{}{background fill}},
}

\tikzset{
  background draw/.style={draw=#1},
  background draw/.default={white},
  draw on/.style={alt=#1{}{background draw}},
}

\tikzset{
  background filldraw/.style 2 args={draw=#1, fill=#2},
  background filldraw/.default={white}{white},
  filldraw on/.style={alt=#1{}{background filldraw}},
}

\tikzset{
  background shade/.style={#1},
  background shade/.default={top color=white, bottom color=white},
  shade on/.style={alt=#1{}{background shade}},
}

\tikzset{
  background shadedraw/.style 2 args={draw=#1, #2},
  background shadedraw/.default={white}{top color=white, bottom color=white},
  shadedraw on/.style={alt=#1{}{background shadedraw}},
}



\newcommand{\tikzmark}[1]{\tikz[remember picture] \node[coordinate] (#1) {#1};}

\setbeamerfont{caption}{size=\tiny}
\setlength\abovecaptionskip{0pt}
\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]

\usetikzlibrary{positioning, shapes.arrows,shadows.blur}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,backgrounds}



\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Example}

    \begin{columns}
    \begin{column}{.5\textwidth}

    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[]
                \node [inner sep=0pt,above right]
                {\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image-duck}};

                \path (1.3,0.7) coordinate (Nodefig);
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \end{column}


    \begin{column}{.5\textwidth}

     \tikz[baseline]{ \node[align=center] (n1) {Test};}

    \end{column}
    \end{columns}




 \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
         \node<1-> [thin, red,opacity=.3, fill=red,fill opacity=0.2,ellipse,minimum width=2cm,minimum height=1.5cm] (foo)  at (Nodefig) {};

         \path[->,line width=0.8pt,color=BrickRed]<1-> (n1) edge [out=-180, in=0] (foo);
 \end{tikzpicture}

\end{frame}



\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: My mistake. I was not clear. I do not want to draw a ellipse that surrounds all my figure.I have corrected the figure.

Comment: @diedro I adapted my answer, but the answer is the same: use a node

Comment: @diedro Please also note that the `\tikzstyle` macro is obsolete

Comment: Sorry, Could you be more specific, please?

Comment: @diedro Don't use the macro `\tikzstyle`, see my answer how you can do the same thing with `\tikzset`